# what this means in Javascript "typeof(arguments[0])"

Tags: javascript, arguments, typeof

I have found this in my code, probably someone has done prior to me. 
I am unable to get what exactly this line of code does. what will arguments[0] do here.

```
        typeof(arguments[0])
```

Entire code is this:

```
 var recommendedHeight = (typeof(arguments[0]) === "number") ? arguments[0] : null;
```

The problem is I always get `recommendedHeight` as `null`. any idea when this returns any other value ?

Comment: Have a look at [Optional arguments in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19572212/1048572) for an example

Comment: Do you know what the [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) is? If so, then what is your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every function in JavaScript automatically receives two additional parameters: `this` and `arguments`. The value of `this` depends on the invocation pattern, could be the global browser context (e.g., window object), function itself, or a user supplied value if you use `.apply()`. The `arguments` parameter is an array-like object of all parameters passed into the function. For example if we defined the following function..

```
function add(numOne, numTwo) {
  console.log(arguments);
  return numOne + numTwo;
}
```

And used it like so..

`add(1, 4);`

This would return 5 of course, and also show the arguments array in the console `[1, 4]`. What this allows you to do is pass and access more parameters than those defined by your function, powerful stuff. For instance..

```
add(1, 4, "extra parameter 1", "extra parameter 2", "extra parameter n");
```

We would see in the console `[1, 4, "extra parameter 1", "extra parameter 2", "extra parameter n"]`. Now in our function we could access `"extra parameter 1"` via `arguments[2]`.

Your code checks the type of the first item in the arguments array (e.g., number, string, etc) and it does so using a ternary operator.

Expanding your code may make it more clear:

```
var recommendedHeight;

//if the first argument is a number
if ( typeof(arguments[0]) === "number" ) {
  //set the recommendedHeight to the first argument passed into the function
  recomendedHeight = arguments[0];
} else {
  //set the recommended height to null
  recomendedHeight = null;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Great explanation Joshua.

Answer (score 0):

That means:

If the variable type of arguments[0] is a number, then recommendedHeight gets the value of arguments[0], otherwise set it to null.

Probably arguments is an array containing some attributes, and its first record should contain the recommended height. This is why it should be a number.